# Why alpha Andromedae is also known as 21 Andromedae?

Tags: constellations

I'm revising the Hipparcos catalogue and I've found that alpha Andromeda and 21 Andromedae has the same HIP (677).

Why alpha Andromedae is also known as 21 Andromedae?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stars have multiple names when they are included in multiple catalogues.

The designation $\alpha$ And is the name in the [Bayer classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_designation).

21 And is the same star's name in the [catalogue compiled by John Flamsteed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamsteed_designation).

If you run [this query](https://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Alpha%20And&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id) through the CDS "SIMBAD" database you can see all the names of this star (there are 60 listed).

[image: SIMBAD identifiers for Alpha And]

Comment: He, and it even has twice the name 'Hip 677' :)